# Making a bingo game using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../jquerylib/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Bingo!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>THE BINGO GAME</h1>
    <div>
        <table align="center" valign="middle">
            <tr>
                <td id="1" class="num"></td>
                <td id="2" class="num"></td>
                <td id="3" class="num"></td>
                <td id="4" class="num"></td>
                <td id="5" class="num"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="6" class="num"></td>
                <td id="7" class="num"></td>
                <td id="8" class="num"></td>
                <td id="9" class="num"></td>
                <td id="10" class="num"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="11" class="num"></td>
                <td id="12" class="num"></td>
                <td id="13" class="num"></td>
                <td id="14" class="num"></td>
                <td id="15" class="num"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="16" class="num"></td>
                <td id="17" class="num"></td>
                <td id="18" class="num"></td>
                <td id="19" class="num"></td>
                <td id="20" class="num"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="21" class="num"></td>
                <td id="22" class="num"></td>
                <td id="23" class="num"></td>
                <td id="24" class="num"></td>
                <td id="25" class="num"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <button align="center" id="genRand">Generate random table</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        class Player {

            // bingo status of a player. 5 for a BINGO!!
            _bingoStatus = 0;

            // Wining status of a player. Only true if this._bingoStatus is 5
            win = (this._bingoStatus == 5) ? true : false;

            // Player name
            name = "default_name";

            // Set name
            constructor(n = "") {
                this.name = n;
            }

            currentPoint() {
                return this._bingoStatus;
            }

            addOne() {
                this._bingoStatus += 1;
            }
        }

        // Some extra function

        // Sort out duplicated elements in array
        function unique(val, idx, self) {
            return self.indexOf(val) === idx;
        }
        /*
            Use: var unqArr = [...].filter(unique);
        */

        // Check if a array is contained in another array
        /*
            ES6 one-lined answer:
            var mainArr = [...];
            var contArr = [...];

            var contain = contArr.every(
                i => mainArr.includes(i)
            );
        */


        // Initialization of global variables

        // Current player. Singleplayer only for testing
        var p = new Player('beta');
        // var p1 = new Player('player1');
        // var p2 = new Player('player2');


        // Ready state of a game
        var gameReady = false;
        var val = [], ids = [];
        var checked = [];
        // All of the possible diagonals, rows and columns for a letter
        // IMPORTANT
        var bingoArray = [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [1, 6, 11, 16, 21],
            [2, 7, 12, 17, 22],
            [3, 8, 13, 18, 23],
            [4, 9, 14, 19, 24],
            [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
            [1, 7, 13, 19, 25],
            [5, 9, 13, 17, 21]
        ]

        // ID of slots in table
        /*
            1  2  3  4  5
            6  7  8  9  10
            11 12 13 14 15
            16 17 18 19 20
            21 22 23 24 25
        */

        $('#genRand').click(function () {

            // Change the "gameReady" state
            gameReady = true;

            // Create array for random dispose of number on the table
            for (let i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
                val.push(i); ids.push(i);
            }

            // If both the arrays are not empty
            while (val.length && ids.length) {

                // ... then randomize/shuffle them
                val.sort(function () { return 0.5 - Math.random(); });
                ids.sort(function () { return 0.5 - Math.random(); });

                // Because the values in the arrays are random, so choosing the
                // last element of the array is like choosing a random number
                $('#' + ids.pop()).html(val.pop());
            }

            // Remove "clicked" attribute when reset the table
            $('.num').removeAttr('clicked');

            // Reset the 'checked' array
            checked = [];
            _bingoStatus = 0;
        });



        $('.num').click(function () {

            // Check the ready state of the game, preventing the player from clicking randomly
            if (gameReady) {
                // A clicked "button" will receive the "true" property 
                // for "clicked" attribute so that it cannot be clicked again,
                // avoiding error and cheating if possible. Idk...
                $(this).attr('clicked', true);

                // Get the id of the element that has just been checked
                var justChecked = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

                // Add it to 'checked' array to find later
                checked.push(justChecked);
                checked = checked.filter(unique);

// IMPORTANT        
/*
For each square clicked, this will check if any array of the bingoArray
is a subarray of 'checked' array. If do, increase the point by 1

But what I want is that for example, the ids of the clicked squares are
[1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 2, 3, 4, 5] (first row and first column), the p.addOne()
should only be called twice because I only choose one row and one column

As the code runs, p.addOne() is called six times with the example above.

Moreover, if for example, I click on the bottom left square, the console should
only log out p.currentPoint() is 2 (if everything is perfect) or 6 (using my algorithm). 
The console here logs out 8 instead.
*/
                for (let i = 0; i < bingoArray.length; i++) {
                    if (
                        bingoArray[i].every(
                            j => checked.includes(j)
                        )
                    )
                        p.addOne();
                        console.log(bingoArray[i], checked, p.currentPoint());
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

div {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* 
    height: 400px; 
    background: #eeeeee;
    width: 400px;
    */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0)
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Google Sans', 'Segeo UI';
}

table,
button {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.num {
    background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
    color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.num:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 46, 145, 0.726);
    color: rgb(209, 209, 209);
}

.num[clicked=true] {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #000;
}

.num[clicked=true]:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.315);
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sum {
    color: rgb(47, 99, 167);
}
```

Directory tree

```
/home/$USER/localhost/jquery
    /games
        /bingo
            >index.html
            >style.css
    /jquerylib
        /dist
            >jquery.js
            >jquery.min.js
```

I'm creating the game Bingo using HTML, CSS and JS (jQuery for events) but I'm having an error.

When you open index.html up with such directory, you'll see a page with a 5 by 5 table. When you click on "Generate random table" button, the game will start.

Then try to click the whole first row, while having the console windows show up. The last number is my bingo point. After clicking the whole first row, the point is 1.

Try to click another square or an already blacked out square. The score should be still be 1 but the console shows 2.

Go back to the code where there are `// IMPORTANT` and I'll explain the error more in details

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Give an example, a desired result and what happened. Also what your debugging / research has revealed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of your code can be reorganized and improved upon. The easiest "fix" is to reset p._bingoStatus to 0 right before the for loop. That way, already found bingos are not counted twice.

```
p._bingoStatus = 0;
```

Your current implementation indicates that win is true when there are **exactly** 5 bingo's on the board. Is that what you really want? This is what I think you actually want

```
win = this._bingoStatus  > 0;
```